# backend magento system.xml

Tags: xml, magento, system

I am new to magento and I have quite a few problems. I'm trying to add a new section in backend but when I go to System->Configuration I receive the error:

```
'This page is not working'
```

system.xml

```
<config>
<tabs>
    <packt>
        <label>Packt</label>
        <sort_order>400</sort_order>
    </packt>
</tabs>
<sections>
    <helloworld translate="label" module="helloworld">
        <label>Helloworld</label>
        <tab>packt</tab>
        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        <groups>
        </groups>
    </helloworld>
</sections>
```

I must say that if I delete the system.xml the System->Configuration works.

The system.xml path is:

app/code/local/Packt/HelloWorld/etc/system.xml

Also the adminhtml.xml is not working because it returns an empty magento admin page. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
        <tabs>
            <packt translate="label">
                <label>Packt</label>
                <sort_order>400</sort_order>
            </packt>
        </tabs>
        <sections>
            <helloworld translate="label" module="helloworld">
                <label>Helloworld</label>
                <tab>packt</tab>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

                <groups>
                    <options translate="label" module="helloworld">
                        <label>Configuration</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <fields>
                            <mytext translate="label">
                                <label>My Text</label>
                                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            </mytext>
                        </fields>
                    </options> 
                 </groups>
            </helloworld>
        <sections>
     </config>
```

Comment: probably you did not create empty Data.php class in helper directory

Comment: If my answer help you, please accept it so it will help other in community as well.